# Windows Spell Checking Service: Is there additional information available?

Tags: c#, windows

I've found that Windows has a spell checking service (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869748(v=vs.85).aspx). I'm not finding much about this at the moment.

Does anyone have more information on this library?

Specifically:

- Are there .NET bindings available (it appears to a COM lib)?
- Are there examples available?
- Which operating systems are supported?
- Are any Microsoft applications using this lib?
- Are any third party applications using this lib?

Comment: The documentation you linked to appears to have [a sample project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/spell-checking-client-aea0148c). I don't know if there are .NET bindings; probably not, it is a very new API and likely hasn't been added to .NET. There might be a third-party implementation, but you'll need Google to find that, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I Googled and didn't find anything before asking here. Sometimes people have information/experience that's not indexed on the Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Only COM
- [Examples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/spell-checking-provider-4cbec195) (for C++)
- "The Spell Checking API is available beginning with the Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012" - in you article
- Using in [github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=IComprehensiveSpellCheckProvider%20&type=Code&ref=searchresults)

Upd: For another OS version you may use: http://www.crawler-lib.net/nhunspell

Comment: Ah, Github. Forget I could search there. No mention of Windows 7 but I'm curious if there's a roadmap about it. Still too many Win 7 users in my user base to ignore.

Comment: Using nhunspell right now. Problem is users have to update their custom dictionaries for each app (including mine). I'm curious in this service because it might be a way to mitigate this issue. Only works though it others are using it.